# Laravel nova 1.1.8 and higher Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on filter icon click

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-nova

Laravel version: 5.7

When updating Laravel nova to a version higher then 1.1.7 when on a ResourceIndex page. Clicking on the filter icon results in the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (nova-custom-filters:3752)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:98488)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:96735)
    at Watcher.get (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:97105)
    at new Watcher (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:97094)
    at mountComponent (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:96742)
    at VueComponent.webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js.Vue.$mount (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:102494)
    at VueComponent.webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js.Vue.$mount (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:104907)
    at init (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:98074)
    at createComponent (vendor.js?id=f1774ad54c9d6dde0d50:99545)
```

Even when I create a brand new filter and only load this filter on the resource.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan view:clear` after upgrade ?

Comment: Can you please provide the code for filter

Answer (score 0):

1) Install a brand new Laravel 5.7 installation.

2) Install Nova. (`php artisan nova:install` and `php artisan nova:publish`)

3) Create a user.

4) Log into Nova.

5) See the error.

This error is NOT reproducible when upgrading for some reason. Once I replaced the `nova-assets` directory with a working copy, the test site worked. Once I deleted the `nova-assets` directory and re-published the Nova assets, it still works, even with a cleared browser cache.

POSSIBLE FIX (May be why it still works after republishing):

`cd` to the laravel/nova vendor directory.

Following this 5 steps I solved the problem but you need to rename `webpack.mix.js.dist` to w`ebpack.mix.js` before run `npm run dev`.

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

Delete the `public/nova-assets` directory.

Make sure to run `php artisan nova:publish --force` to get the latest assets after update.